# Cypress intercepted api request canceled (with Err_empty_Reposnse) even though the cy.wait is still in progress

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I have written the following code to wait for the API:

```
cy.intercept('POST', generateAPI).as('generateReport')
        cy.wait('@generateReport', {timeout:480000})
        .its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

Somehow the api request gets aborted before the wait time of 8 minutes completes.

[image]

Can some one help me with what might be causing the issue.

One more thing, i noticed everytime the API gets aborted within 4 minutes with error as ERR_empty_Repsponse. Please find the screenshot below:
[image]

I have tried n number of things to get this working but still no luck. Let me know if anyone else has faced similar issue and found a solution for it.

----------- Updates as of April 8th 2021:

With new release of cypress 7.0.0, the API gives back a response and is no longer hitting the Err_empth_Response But still the cy.wait() gives an error that the request never occurred.

[image]

Comment: can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was am issue with cypress older version. It is resolved in cypress 7.0.0. version onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Put `"chromeWebSecurity": false` in your `cypress.json` file and try again!